# Obfuscar .NET Obfuscation Breaks References to My.Computer

Tags: vb.net, obfuscation, obfuscar

We are running .NET application with references to `My.Computer` in an Obfuscar obfuscated dll.  It seems that these references throw an exception at run time.  For instance:

Code:

```
Dim str As String = My.Computer.Name
```

Message:

```
The type initializer for 'a.aa' threw an exception.
```

Inner Exception:

```
   System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'a`1.W'.
   at a.aa.a`1..ctor()
   at a.aa..cctor()
```

From these error messages, it looks like Obfuscar is obfuscating the reference to `My.Computer.Name`.  (.NET Reflector shows `aa.A.Name`.) I'm not sure how that makes sense since it's an "external" reference.

Using a different way to get the computer name does appear to work, but we have a lot of references to `My.Computer` in our code, and it would be good to figure out how to get Obfuscar to not break these, rather than have to tiptoe around them.

I think I am looking for an Obfuscar XML entry to skip these references, unless anyone has any better ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone finds this, our solution was to set the following flag to false:

```
<Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="false" />
```

This obviously reduces some of the security of the obfuscation, but it solved our issue for now.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because, so often OPs add a comment that they solved the problem without explaining why, and the post becomes useless and time-wasting. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback!